# Test discovery fails using DRF APITestCase but not django's TestCase

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework's [APITestCase](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#api-test-cases) class, Visual Studio Code does not discover my `unittest` tests.  I've configured vscode to use unittest and given it the path to my django app.  I have toggled between jedi and ms's language server for python.

I can run the tests manually, using `python manage.py test`.

If I switch to using Django's provided `django.test.TestCase`, vscode discovers the tests and creates the adornments.  I have also tried rest_framework's two other test cases: APISimpleTestCase, APITransactionTestCase and neither worked.

My test class is very simple, essentially the following:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

# * cannot get vscode to discover tests with this
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

service_path = "/api/v0.1/service"


# class PathLookupTests(TestCase):
class PathLookupTests(APISimpleTestCase):
    def test_responding(self):
        uri = "valid_uri"

        resp = self.client.get(f"{service_path}/?uri={uri}")
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

In the `Python Test Log` I saw the following traceback once, but cannot repeat it:

```sh
  File "/Users/bfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-server-eval/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1123, in setUpClass
    super().setUpClass()
  File "/Users/bfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-server-eval/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 197, in setUpClass
    cls._add_databases_failures()
  File "/Users/bfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-server-eval/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 218, in _add_databases_failures
    cls.databases = cls._validate_databases()
  File "/Users/bfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-server-eval/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 204, in _validate_databases
    if alias not in connections:
TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionHandler' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging, I now see that django's test runner does not work in vscode. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/73

The solution, at least for me, was to use [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Here's the example above but using pytest-django (after setting up my `pytest.ini` file to point at my django app)

```py
service_path = "/api/v0.1/service"

def test_responding(client):
    uri = "valid_uri"

    resp = client.get(f"{service_path}/?uri={uri}")
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```